# Is T an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let U, V, and W be complex vector spaces. Consider the map$$T : (U ⊕ V) ⊗ W → (U ⊗ W) ⊕ (V ⊗ W)$$
given by$$T((|u\rangle+|v\rangle)⊗ |w\rangle)= |u\rangle⊗|w\rangle+|v\rangle⊗|w\rangle$$
Is T an isomorphism? How to show it?
I have thought it for a while, but I totally have no idea about it......
What make it even worse is that I don't quite familiar with tensor product. I was wondering whether it's linear. I tried to write it with the form $T(a|u\rangle+b|v\rangle)=aT|u\rangle+bT|v\rangle$ but the addition of tensor make me more confused .It seems like it's onto, but I don't know how to show it is one-to-one. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You also need to make sure $T$ is well defined. I personally prefer to use the universal property of tensor products to get a handle on maps out of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You could try to define a bilinear function from
$ \bigl( U \oplus V \bigr) \times W$ to $ (U \otimes W) \oplus (V \otimes W)$ by mapping $(u+v, w)$ to $u \otimes w + v \otimes w,$ and you could use the universal property of the tensor product. This should set you on the right track. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product.